# rails and cancan - how to restrict the company show action to users owner in has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, has-many-through

i'm trying to solve an user's ability problem with cancan gem.
company and users are associated through user_company_assignment in such a way that a company has many user and the users has and belongs to many companies
I would like to restrict the show action of a company only to those users associated with the company. below there is the code of the two models and a snip of ability.rb with the initialize role inheritance and the method for the seller user, but this is not working, it show me always the company detail.

Company.rb

```
has_many :user_company_assignments
has_many :user, :through => :user_company_assignments
```

User.rb

```
has_many :user_company_assignments
has_many :companies, :through => :user_company_assignments
```

Ability.rb

```
def initialize(user)
  @user = user || User.new # for guest
  @user.roles.each { |role| send(role.name.downcase) }
end

def seller
  can :manage, :all
  cannot :destroy, :all

  can :show, Company do |company|
    company.user_ids.include? @user.id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is due to ability precedence: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence

This line overrides all following abilities: `can :manage, :all`

Since you've already stated that a seller can manage all, the seller can perform any kind of action on a Company, regardless of the other `can` statement.

One solution would be to use `cannot`, as you did with `:destroy`. It will override the `:manage, :all` clause.

```
def seller
  can :manage, :all
  cannot :destroy, :all
  cannot :show, Company do |company|
    !company.user_ids.include? @user.id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `load_and_authorize_resource` method in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ok jesper, i have changed my ability.rb and it works but i'm not sure that this is the best method to set the ability, it is strange the i need to specify each Models that a seller has the permission to the show action. tell me if is it the best way to do that:

Ability.rb

```
def seller
  can [:index, :create], :all
  cannot :destroy, :all

  can :show, Company do |company|
    company.user_ids.include? @user.id
  end

  can :show, [Report, Client]

end
```

Comment: Did you read my edit? You can override `can :manage, :all` with `cannot`